# Username checking in JSP as it is typed

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP page where a user is required to input a desired username and password. If the username already exists then there will be an error (in red) shown just beside the input that the username has already been taken. And if the username is new then (in green) a message will be displayed beside the input that the username is available. The checking should be done parallely with the user's input. After the username selection is successful then the page will be directed to the login page. How do i design this?

Comment: An example should be posted.

Comment: okay, i'll keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: JSP is completely executed before showing the page to user. So if you want a quick feedback to user-generated events (login typing) you need to involve Javascript. I'd recommend this way:

- Add jQuery JS library to your page.
- Design CSS classes for "green" and "red" states of input field.
- Add "onChange" event listener to the field. Its handler should send an AJAX request to the server side with current user input.
- Implement server-side handler (servlet or whatever you use) that receives user input and checks if it is good.
- AJAX "onSuccess" event listener then will receive response from server and set proper CSS class to the field.

jQuery docs to look at: [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [change handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Thank you Alex, unfortunately I do not know AJAX so it will take me a while to code what you said. This cleared my doubt that you need to involve Javascript for user-generated events which JSP cannot do.